# The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version, C++ error

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am getting error while running the C++ code in Visual Studio Code, I am not able to run any code in my editor, here there is the image of the error I had search many time about this but not get anything. I tried to use '|' in place of '&&' but still there is no improvement. My VS Code is up to date. would anyone like to share some fix for this. It seems that there is error in the '#include <bits/stdc++.h>' file as it says that there is error in line 1 and char 46, char 51 etc ...

[image: this is the image of error]

Any information regarding this will be appreciated, thank you for your time ...

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your version of powershell. I have the same error if I type `dir && dir` in PS 5.1 but 7.1.1 handles it fine.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with C++, it's trying to run two commands in powershell with `&&` between.

Comment: Related: [https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.2](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.2)

Comment: Also: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: `&&` is not the way to execute multiple command in PowerShell, but `;`

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 6):

`&&` is not the way to execute multiple command in PowerShell, replace it by `;`

Comment: Beginning with PowerShell 7 you can use `&&` as Pipeline Chain Operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7.1#pipeline-chain-operators

Comment: the OP just has very limited knowledge of powershell and C++ so I don't believe they install powershell 7 which isn't included by default themselves

Answer (score 0):

"&&" may not be distinguished by "AND" by the compiler. You should use ";" instead of it.